# can we access the columns of a table as array in sql?

Tags: sql, arrays

is there any way to access the columns of a table as array in sql?
eg:
   **table1**

```
NAME
abc
def
ghi
jkl
```

can we access it like NAME[0]?

Comment: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/arrays-in-sql-that-avoid-repeated-groups/

Comment: Your question a little ambiguous. I don't think you need to access them in an array, but rather index them through numbers is what you mean.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  You could reference the column name directly if you needed that specific column from that specific table.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no.

Long answer would depend on your database and likely would not be a plain sql.

Answer (score 0):

SQL doesn't support arrays (yet), but you can create the same effect by using 'WITH' keyword for select or ' IN' for WHERE statement  . 
Sounds ambiguous but I will love to expand if you provide us with more information .

Comment: i have inserted the values from excel file

echo "insert into table_a(value1,value2) 
values ('${a[$i]}', '${b[$i]}');" >> script.sql

now i want to append a column value 3 from another table in this table as it is..
so i am thinking of getting it in form of array and insert like  ${a[$i]} in above query